# applescript/shell script - check if image

Tags: file, bash, shell, applescript

How do I check if a file is an image in applescript or shell script. I am aware of the `file` command but it doesn't say if it is an image or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about checking mime type of the file?

```
 file --mime
```

Comment: If you add `--brief`, the output won't include the filename, which may make it easier to parse.